# Empty association table when trying to save many-to-many relationships between entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping

I have `User` entities ([User mapping file](http://pastebin.com/rj0s92tK)) and
`Role` entities ([Role mapping file](http://pastebin.com/ZKHhxkNf)). I create
some `User`s and `Role`s, assign roles to users and users to roles, save the
whole lot, retrieve a `User` and test some assumptions (which fail).

Here's my test code:

```
[Test]
public void TestUsersAndRolesWithoutWrappers()
{
    //Ensure numOfUsers <= numOfRoles
    int numOfUsers = 3, numOfRoles = 4, i;
    User userW = null;
    Role roleW = null;
    List<User> userWList = new List<User>(numOfUsers);
    List<Role> roleWList = new List<Role>(numOfRoles);
    for (i = 0; i < numOfRoles; i++)
    {
        roleW = new Role();
        roleW.Name = "Role" + (i + 1);
        roleWList.Add(roleW);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < numOfUsers; i++)
    {
        userW = new User();
        userW.Uname = "username" + (i + 1);
        userW.Email = "username" + (i + 1) + "@example.com";
        userW.Roles.Add(roleWList[i]);
        roleWList[i].Users.Add(userW);
        userWList.Add(userW);

    }
    userWList[0].Roles.Add(roleWList[numOfRoles - 1]);
    roleWList[numOfRoles - 1].Users.Add(userWList[0]);
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        foreach (Role listRoleW in roleWList)
        {
            session.Save(listRoleW);
        }
        foreach (User listUserW in userWList)
        {
            session.Save(listUserW);
        }
    }
    using (ISession session2 = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        User fromDb = session2.Get<User>(userWList[0].ID);
        Assert.AreNotSame(userWList[0], fromDb);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, fromDb.Roles.Count); //This fails, as the actual count is 0
    }
}
```

The Roles and Users tables get filled-in as expected, the UserRoles table gets
created, but is empty.  So what am I missing?

Configuration:

- .Net 4.5
- NHibernate 4.x
- SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping seems to be correct. Just not sure what is the session default *FlushMode*.

To be sure, that it is not `None`, try to append into first using the `session.Flush();`.

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    ...
    session.Flush();
}
```

Reason why simple insert into User and Role is happening is due to the fact, that these two have ID generator set as native:

```
<generator class="native" />
```

Which means, that even without session.Flush() NHibernate must do INSERT to obtain ID

[9.6. Flush](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)

> ... Except when you explicity **`Flush()`**, there are absolutely no guarantees about when the Session executes the ADO.NET calls, only the order in which they are executed. ...

Comment: Thanks, that worked! What should I set the FlushMode to so that Flush is called whenever the session/using clause ends (i.e., it's Dispose() method is called)?

Comment: Wow, that is not easy to say in general... That's why we **do have these options** ;) But, in web... I do call `Flush()` *(explicit)* before Commit... and I can react if something goes wrong. Other words, before Commit I DO assure in code, that all stuff is **flushed**. In tests.. I do `Flush()` as well but before the Rollback *(to be sure that it is not just "virtual" working test)* - and also anyhwere I need *(e.g. in the Tests Using piece...)* also, we I do step into `OpenSession()` factory method *(e.g. AOP, custom factory)* and explicitly set it to intended kind... hope it helps a bit  ;)